# How to remove items within a column based on their given value?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
ab = {
    'Category': ['AD', 'AG'],
    'C1_count': ['agitation, care=4; anxiety=3; ataxia=1; cognitive/trek=0', 'agitation=4; anxiety,check=0; ataxia=1; cognitive=1'],
    'C2_count': ['agitation=0; anxiety=1; ataxia=1; cognitive=0', 'agitation=0; anxiety=1; ataxia, bee and jee=0; cognitive=0']
}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(ab)
```

df1

```
    Category    C1_count                                                    C2_count
0   AD          agitation, care=4; anxiety=3; ataxia=1; cognitive/trek=0    agitation=0; anxiety=1; ataxia=1; cognitive=0
1   AG          agitation=4; anxiety,check=0; ataxia=1; cognitive=1         agitation=0; anxiety=1; ataxia, bee and jee=0; cognitive=0
```

I want to remove the terms in dataframe that equals to `0`. The expected output looks as follows:

```
    Category    C1_count                                C2_count
0   AD          agitation, care=4; anxiety=3; ataxia=1  anxiety=1; ataxia=1
1   AG          agitation=4; ataxia=1; cognitive=1      anxiety=1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try via `applymap()`:

```
f=lambda x:';'.join([y for y in x.split(';') if '=0' not in y])
#Finally:
df1[['C1_count','C2_count']]=df1[['C1_count','C2_count']].applymap(f)
```

output of `df`:

```
  Category  C1_count                                C2_count
0   AD      agitation, care=4; anxiety=3; ataxia=1  anxiety=1; ataxia=1
1   AG      agitation=4; ataxia=1; cognitive=1      anxiety=1
```

Comment: this code works partially. because it also removes the word when word name contains `0`. For example `agitation0 use=5` also will get removed.

Comment: @user288925 updated answer...kindly have a look and let me know if there is any more case  like this as well **:)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to match the pattern with count=0;

```py
for col in ('C1_count', 'C2_count'):
    df1[col] = df1[col].str.replace('\w.*?=0;\s+', '', regex=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [`pandas.Series.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) with a regex:

```
df1['C1_count'] = df1['C1_count'].str.replace('(; )?[^= ]+=0| ?[^= ]+=0;',
                                              '', regex=True)
df1['C2_count'] = df1['C2_count'].str.replace('(; )?[^= ]+=0| ?[^= ]+=0;',
                                              '', regex=True)
```

output:

```
  Category  C1_count                                C2_count
0   AD      agitation, care=4; anxiety=3; ataxia=1  anxiety=1; ataxia=1
1   AG      agitation=4; ataxia=1; cognitive=1      anxiety=1
```

Comment: this code works partially. because it also removes the word when word name contains `0`. For example `agitation0 use=5` also will get removed

Comment: Have you checked? I'm pretty sure it doesn't. It requires a "=" right before the 0 for a match.